# How to add new account, update and delete in bing ads under any user account by php?

Tags: php

I have tried below code for updating but it did not work it showed error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Cannot create an abstract class. in D:\xampp\htdocs\bingTest\UpdateAccount.php:81 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\bingTest\UpdateAccount.php(81): SoapClient->__call('UpdateAccount', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\bingTest\UpdateAccount.php(81): SoapClient->UpdateAccount(Object(BingAds\CustomerManagement\UpdateAccountRequest)) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\bingTest\UpdateAccount.php(62): UpdateAccount(Object(BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy), Object(BingAds\CustomerManagement\AdvertiserAccount)) #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\bingTest\UpdateAccount.php on line 81

```
$wsdl = "https://clientcenter.api.sandbox.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/CustomerManagement/v9/CustomerManagementService.svc?singleWsdl";

$proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, $UserName, $Password, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, null, null);

$last_modified_time=GetAccount($proxy,$AccountId);

$account_obj=new AdvertiserAccount();
$account_obj->AccountType='Advertisement';
$account_obj->CountryCode="US";
$account_obj->CurrencyType="USD";
$account_obj->Id=$AccountId;
$account_obj->LastModifiedTime=$last_modified_time;
$account_obj->Name="Test Account";
$account_obj->AccountLifeCycleStatus='Pause';

UpdateAccount($proxy, $account_obj);

function GetAccount($proxy,$AccountId)
{
    $account_obj=new GetAccountRequest();
    $account_obj->AccountId=$AccountId;

    return $proxy->GetService()->GetAccount($account_obj)->Account->LastModifiedTime;
}


function UpdateAccount($proxy, $update_account_info)
{
    $request = new UpdateAccountRequest();
    $request->Account = $update_account_info;

    return $proxy->GetService()->UpdateAccount($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you still need a solution. You need to do this:

```
    $encodedAccount = new \SoapVar(
        $account, 
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
        'AdvertiserAccount', 
        'https://bingads.microsoft.com/Customer/v9/Entities'
    );

    $request->Account = $encodedAccount;
```